# Creating sequential rows in DB table when Clob spills

Tags: java, database, jpa, optimization, db2

We have a CLOB entry that is bigger than the column size CLOB. Instead of increasing the Column CLOB size what I came up with is to chop spills and place it on a different row. Is this beneficial or is there a more beneficial way?
We use DB2, Java, & JPA.

E.g. My table Numbers has columns of Pkey, NumberName, and Digit. Digit is 10mB CLOB.

Problem example would be, I have a new String coming in that is 12mB CLOB. This will cause an error.
What I was thinking of doing is to add another column that holds a sequence then chop off spills and spills of that spill.

E.g. My table Numbers will have the columns, Pkey, NumberName, Digit, and Sequence.

Sequence is for enabling me to know which to start off first and which to add second and so on.

---

### | Pkey   | NumberName | Digit  | Sequence|

### | 00001| Pi                     | 10mb | 1                |

### | 00002| Pi                     | 2mb   | 2                |

Chances of having something exceed this 10mb is rare, around 1 every 1.5 years and generally would not be practical to exceed 5 five folds, which is why I'm sticking to increasing CLOB size.

Comment: and how are you planning on mapping that in JPA? You can't add arbitrary columns dynamically.

Comment: @Neil, say I go with this route. The column would be added in to the table via creating a new column. We are not planning on creating the column dynamically via any means. Once something above is setup, you can query everything that matches the NumberName and sort by the sequence. It would also be logical to add 1 to every existing row before accommodating the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just creating extra work for yourself and adding an opportunity for errors.

CLOB columns can be defined as big as 2 GB; however, only the actual size of CLOB data in each row will be allocated, so there will be no wasted space if you define your CLOB column to fit your largest value. There is no reason to artificially split your LOBs.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21970879

Comment: Hi Mustaccio, would you be able to link to a source? I can't for the life of me find 1.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you do which you have told then it will cause performance issue while travelling the table rows in bigger application. Because every time you fire query on this table it have to find and traverse all the records and every time this kind of data comes and you chop off them, table will become larger. So either you increase column size or if you don't want to increase then do this way. First 10mb data will go into table A and another table B have it's chop off values and maintain sequences in this table A.

Comment: I don't want to just increase the CLOB size because then it wont be maintainable. e.g. increase it to 20mb but then maybe sometime a 25mb data goes in.

Although exceeding this 10mb is rare though, to give you some statistics, once in 1.5 years.

Having 2 tables for 10mb of data each to sequence them is more efficient? Although it doesn't sound so maintainable either.

Comment: As ans by mustaccio above. it will not occupy whole space if you give column size like 1gb. it will occupy only what your data carries. so no worries about increasing column size. and yes, for once in 1.5 years, it is not feasible to create second table. if you are saying that you have scenario like more than 10mb is once in 1.5 yr then go with your solution. but it will increase your extra work.

Comment: ...why would you put overflow in a **second** table?  If he has to increase it again later he's in the exact same position now, only TableA has the first 10mb and TableB has... everything else, potentially in multiple rows.  Why not just make the TableA CLOB size **0** at that point?  You're needlessly increasing the complexity of the system in a way that's pretty much guaranteed to shoot you in the foot (at least the one-table version is self-contained!).

Answer (score 1):

Increasing the size of the CLOB is the **right** answer.  Either increase it to 20MB and increase it again if you get the 25MB...or just increase it to 50MB now.

Heck, consider increasing it to 2GB now...unused space isn't wasted.